# I am a little confused about Big-O Notation with recursive functions

Tags: c, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science

How can I find the running time of a recursive function. For example:

```
void fun_list(LLnode_t * head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("%d ", head-> data);
    if (head->next != NULL) {
        fun_list(head->next);
    }
    printf("%d ", head->data);
}
```

I know that we are supposed to find the running time of the recursive case and the base case. I think the running time of the base case is O(1). How would I go about finding the running time of the recursive case?

Comment: Multiply the complexity of each case by how many times it recurses.

Comment: Just like an iterative process, where you multiply the complexity of the loop body by the number of times it repeats.

Comment: As far as Big-O is concerned, there's no difference between looping and recursing.

Comment: This function prints out the list from the first element to the last, then the last to the first. So, the recursive case visits each element once. Then the last print statement is executed once in every iteration. So, in total the base case is O(1), the recursive case is O(length of the list) and the last print statement is O(1). Therefore, the running time of the function is O(Length of the list).

Comment: Would this be a valid explanation?

Comment: A better explanation is that each call is `O(1)`, and it recurses `n` times, so it's `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity would be O(n), where 'n' is how many times the recursive functions is called. It is basically calculated by multiplying the complexity of the base case by how many times it is called by the recursion. So the complexity is linear.

Comment: However, it is more interesting to say how n connects to the input instead of just saying "Number of iterations". Otherwise, almost anything was O(n). So, in this case n is the length of the list.

Comment: You don't multiply the complexity of the base case, since it only executes once. You multiply the complexity of the recursive cases, since they repeat.